# Tomcat 8 on Azure websites

Tags: java, tomcat, azure, java-8

I can see Azure currently only supports Java 7 and Tomcat 7 or Jetty 9.1. As for the development of a system, the customer is considering Azure as an option for hosting the Java application. The application will be written in Java 8. Does anyone know if Microsoft has any plans for updating their Tomcat server to Tomcat 8? Amazon already got this in [November last year](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/11/05/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-java8-tomcat8/), so I would assume Microsoft would not be waiting too long. Does anyone know if Microsoft has any "official" plans on upgrading it so I don't have to buy an entire VM just for a web app? (Or use Java 7 for that matter)

Comment: you don't need to `buy` and entire VM, you can use AzureRunMe project run `any` version of `any` windows compatible software on Azure Worker Role: https://github.com/azure-contrib/AzureRunMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official statement from Microsoft. But Microsoft are flexible enough and have envisioned your requirement. You can use entirely your own Java build if you want, along with your own build of Tomcat. Of course, the builds have to be compatible with Windows operating system.

For detailed instructions on how to change Java and Tomcat versions, refer to the following article: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/

Comment: Took me a while to get it working. They didn't mention you needed a $ in front of the {port.http} property in the server.xml. The JVM you uploaded also had to correspond with the platform flag which I had set to 32-bit. Uploaded the x86 version of JDK on my pc and it works like a charm.

Comment: Scratch that, that was with the JVM on Azure. I get the exception java.lang.Error: IP Helper Library GetIfTable function failed when starting it. See full log [here](http://pastebin.com/fJqLFm2S). Some people says that it is because it is conflicting with an older Java version, but that was not on Azure.

Comment: just for the sake of trial - can you put earlier version of java but still register as custom. to see if the same error will come. It might be something with compatibility of 1.8 on Windows Server, who knows :/ btw the Azure RunMe is still there. And there are hundreds of commercial live java apps running it on Azure.

Comment: I've been trying to replicate this issue on a vm with Windows Server 2012 Data Center without any luck. Any JDK I set up on it seems to be running just fine. On Azure however, the only JDK I can get working is 1.7 update 51 which is the one that is already installed there. I tried installing 1.7u54 on my vm to try and get a conflict between the two jvms but it seemed that it was running just fine. Sigh, easiest way would just be to make Microsoft update their Java version, hehe. I would assume it as you say, some compatibility with their config/OS.

Comment: Issue solved, had to use [JDK 1.8u0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html#jdk-8-oth-JPR) x86. It has to be the x86 as I haven't enabled x64 on the portal.

Answer (score 0):

I had filed a support ticket with Microsoft, and was told last week by a "Sr. Escalation Engineer" for Windows Azure Web Sites that the Product Group knows of bugs using Java 8, and (direct quote) "It was confirmed that all but the first release of ( version Java 1.8_0 ) will not work due to the bug that was mentioned. Unfortunately there is no workaround until this is fixed."  It appears that if you want to use the latest Java 8 (8u31) you'll have to wait.  Microsoft is working on it, but they were non-committal on an exact date.

Comment: As per this comment by Chris Compy, Sr. Program Manager, Azure Websites, he hopes that Java 8 will be supported by March '15 & has "intention is to provide updates every 6 months" - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-custom-upload/#comment-1833107316