# Installing wordpress on Azurewebsites running Django

Tags: django, wordpress, azure-web-app-service

We are running Django application on Azure websites. We would like to install a blog on www.example.com/blog.

We uploaded wordpress into root directory, www.example.com/blog. But Django URL handler is stopping the request to the subdirectory and issuing an 404 page.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to deploy multiple apps (a wordpress in PHP & a Django in Python) on the same Azure website instance.

So the steps as below, please try.

1. First of all, please check the PHP runtime option of `Application settings` whether enabled on Azure portal, as the figure below, and refer to the offical document [`Configure PHP in Azure App Service Web Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-php-configure) to know more details.

[image]

2. To configure a new entry of `Virtual applications and directories` on Azure portal as the figure below, which is very similar with the other SO thread [How to Deploy Multiple Apps on Azure WebApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781614/how-to-deploy-multiple-apps-on-azure-webapps/40907135#40907135) that you can refer to.

[image]

3. Finally, you can upload the wordpress installation files into the path `site/wwwroot/blog` and install it normally.

Hope it helps.

Comment: appreciate it Peter. But I've done that, however should we add anything in our web.config file? It's throwing 404.

Comment: @VishnuVankayala Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45343655/azurewebsite-django-url-rewrite-for-another-application