# Can we deploy nodejs app and spring-boot app in same Azure-App-Service?

Tags: node.js, azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service

We are using 2 frameworks for developing backend:

- NodeJS
- Spring-Boot

Can we deploy both builds on the same Azure AppService instance?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's similar with the other SO threads [Installing wordpress on Azurewebsites running Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306626/installing-wordpress-on-azurewebsites-running-django/45318593#45318593) and [How to Deploy Multiple Apps on Azure WebApps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781614/how-to-deploy-multiple-apps-on-azure-webapps/40907135#40907135).

You can deploy an application in the path `wwwroot` and deploy the other as a virtual application in the other sub-path of `D:\home` which you configured the virtual directory and path at the tab `Application settings` of your website on Azure portal.

[image]

Here is the steps as reference.

1. Create a directory like `other` in the path `site\wwwroot` via Kudu console.
2. Upload the files of your two applications separately into the path `wwwroot` and `ohter`.
3. Create the `web.config` files separately in their own directory for the different applications, and their content as below.

Sample configuration `web.config` for starting up a SpringBoot jar, which comes from [Deploying Springboot to Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103878/deploying-springboot-to-azure-app-service)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\ROOT.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Sample configuration `web.config` for a Node.js application, please refer to the wiki page [Using a custom web.config for Node apps](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps).

Note to use the different absolute path for configuration to avoid the name conflict.