# I have a server repo that has two Node.js services and common code. How do I deploy this to Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, web, azure-web-app-service

I have App A and App B which has common code in node.js.

```
Commom
d node_modules
    Dal.js
    helpers.js
    logger.js
    package.json
App A
d    node_modules
d    views
d    routes
    app.js
    package.json
App B
d    node_modules
d    views
d   routes
    app.js
   package.json
```

There is start-up script that starts services today and works fine on a local machine.

I couldn't deploy this to Azure Web App. The deployment is failing as it couldn't find package.json at root folder. Is it possible to deploy multiple services to Web App or it only allows one. I know we can make NPM for common and have separate, but it creates long-term problem of knowing/managing bunch of repo's for each service and common code. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure use IIS to host your website and IIS has allowed you to configure multiple *virtual directories* and *applications* within a single website. So, it's possible to deploy multiple services to Web App via [**Virtual Directory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory). For more information, please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781614/how-to-deploy-multiple-apps-on-azure-webapps).

Comment: Can you please clarify, I don't see the links answering the question. Do you mean that I can specify Common as  virtual directory and it will deploy? I tried it, but no luck. I must be missing something.